# in my number generation game, I am not able to wait for all threads to send in their number

Tags: c, multithreading

I am doing this program in C, where in every round each thread generates a random number from 0 to 99, and the thread(s) that generates the highest number scores a point and at the end of all the rounds, the thread(s) with the highest score wins.

I am having trouble figuring out how to wait for the threads to send in all the numbers. The random numbers generated array is initially all -1's and I have tried using a while loop to wait until there are no -1s remaining, but that gives me an infinite loop whereas I should be moving on to find the maximum number generated and assign points accordingly.

(This is my first time using threads, and this is for an operating systems class)

```
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

//store random numbers generated by thread
int* randnums;
//shows whether a thread won or lost
int* res;
// signal for threads to send numbers in
int ready = 0;
//store the score(which is the number of wins for each thread
int* numwins;

//check if there is a -1 in the array
int containsnegative(int* a) {
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    n = (int)n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] == -1) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


void* mythreadfunc(void* toread); 



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //int i;


    pthread_attr_t attr;

    //get number of threads and number of rounds in the game
    int numthreads; 
    numthreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numrounds = atoi(argv[2]);
    srand(time(NULL));

    int threadstocreate = numthreads;

    //pthread_t tid;

    pthread_t* threads;


    threads = malloc(numthreads * sizeof(pthread_t));

    randnums = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numthreads);
    res = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numthreads);
    numwins = (int*)calloc(numthreads, sizeof(int));

    size_t randsize = sizeof(randnums) / sizeof(randnums[0]);
    randsize = (int)randsize;
    for (int x = 0; x < randsize; x++) {
        randnums[x] = -1;
    }

    if (res == NULL) {
        printf("res is null \n");
    }
   
    //set all values in res array to 0. this will be changed to 1 if that thread wins
    for (int k = 0; k < numthreads; k++) {
            res[k] = 0; 
    }

    

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&(threads[i]), &attr, mythreadfunc, (void*)&i);

        printf("thread created\n");
    }

    
    for (int k = 0; k < numrounds; k++) {
        printf("round %d has started\n", k + 1);
        ready = 1;
        // wait for threads to send score in (This is where I am having my error)
        while (containsnegative(randnums) == 1) {
                  
        }
        //find max score
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
            if (randnums[i] > max) {
                max = randnums[i];
            }
        }
        //update score for all threads that scored the maximum
        for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
            if (randnums[i] == max) {
                numwins[i]++;
                printf("Thread %d scored in this round!\n", i + 1);
            }
        }
        //reset randnums back to -1 for the next round
        for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
            randnums[i] = -1;
        }
        //if we are in the last round then print the scores for all of the threads
        if (k == numrounds - 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
                printf("Thread %d scored %d points\n",i+1,numwins[i]);
            }
        }

        
        
    }

    //pthread_join()

    printf("Program Finished\n");

}



void* mythreadfunc(void* toread) {
    // get where to send numbers
    int whereToPut = *((int*)toread);
    // if ready to send the numbers in send it in.
    if (ready == 1) {
        int numgenerated = rand() % 100;
        printf("%d\n", numgenerated);
        printf("\n");
        randnums[whereToPut] = numgenerated;
        printf("%d\n", randnums[whereToPut]);
        pthread_exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);` does not do what you think it does. You need to pass the length of an array as an argument. There are many other posts here on the topic you should search for.

Comment: You can't use `rand` in a multithread program. Use `rand_r` instead with a per-thread seed variable.

Comment: Another issue is that here `pthread_create(&(threads[i]), &attr, mythreadfunc, (void*)&i);` goes out of scope as soon as the loop ends and you have no guarantee that the thread function will run immediately after creation or after the loop, when the address passed as `toread` won't be usable

Comment: I've fixed some bugs https://onlinegdb.com/SyAzmEuzd as a suggestion. Keep in mind that I've not used pthreads in years, so **it's not meant to be any good :)**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for an amusing multithreading problem. The following solution is written in the Ada programming language. Ada tasks are mapped to OS threads except in bare metal systems where the tasks are managed by the Ada runtime.
Task entries allow direct messaging between tasks. In this example the main thread calls the Set_Limits entry to set each task's ID and number of iterations. The Go entry allows another iteration of the random number generation loop in each task. Each task will wait at the accept statement for an entry until another task calls the corresponding entry for the task. Task entries implement the Ada Rendevous logic forcing synchronization points between tasks.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

procedure Main is

   subtype elements is Integer range 1 .. 40;

   Max_Iterations : constant := 20;

   type Buffs is array (elements) of Natural;

   Buffers : Buffs;

   task type Player is
      entry Set_Limits (Id : in Positive; Count : in Positive);
      entry Go;
   end Player;

   task body Player is
      subtype values is Integer range 1 .. 100;
      package rands is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (values);
      use rands;
      Seed     : Generator;
      task_id  : Positive;
      Num_Iter : Positive;
   begin
      Reset (Seed);

      -- suspend until the Set_Limits entry is called
      accept Set_Limits (Id : in Positive; Count : in Positive) do
         task_id  := Id;
         Num_Iter := Count;
      end Set_Limits;

      for I in 1 .. Num_Iter loop
         -- suspend until the Go entry is called
         accept Go;
         Buffers (task_id) := Random (Seed);
      end loop;

   end Player;

   -- create an array of Player tasks. They start immediately.
   players : array (elements) of Player;

   min_id  : elements;
   min_val : Natural;
   max_id  : elements;
   max_val : Natural;
begin
   -- initialize the players
   for I in players'Range loop
      players (I).Set_Limits (I, Max_Iterations);
   end loop;

   -- run game
   for I in 1 .. Max_Iterations loop

      -- zero the values in Buffers then get rand nums
      Buffers := (others => 0);

      -- call the go entry for each task
      for I in players'Range loop
         players (I).Go;
      end loop;

      delay 0.000_1; -- wait 0.1 milliseconds

      min_id  := Buffers'First;
      min_val := Buffers (Buffers'First);
      max_id  := Buffers'First;
      max_val := Buffers (Buffers'First);

      -- find min and max values randomly generated
      for I in Buffers'Range loop
         if Buffers (I) < min_val then
            min_val := Buffers (I);
            min_id  := I;
         end if;
         if Buffers (I) > max_val then
            max_val := Buffers (I);
            max_id  := I;
         end if;
      end loop;

      -- output the max and min values
      Put_Line ("Max Id :" & max_id'Image & " Max value :" & max_val'Image);
      Put_Line ("Min Id :" & min_id'Image & " Min value :" & min_val'Image);
      Put_Line ("-------------");
   end loop;
end Main;
```

A sample output for the program is:

```
Max Id : 1 Max value : 97
Min Id : 16 Min value : 3
-------------
Max Id : 2 Max value : 96
Min Id : 40 Min value : 2
-------------
Max Id : 2 Max value : 100
Min Id : 11 Min value : 1
-------------
Max Id : 34 Max value : 99
Min Id : 13 Min value : 4
-------------
Max Id : 30 Max value : 99
Min Id : 24 Min value : 3
-------------
Max Id : 22 Max value : 100
Min Id : 35 Min value : 1
-------------
Max Id : 3 Max value : 99
Min Id : 27 Min value : 2
-------------
Max Id : 33 Max value : 98
Min Id : 15 Min value : 3
-------------
Max Id : 16 Max value : 99
Min Id : 5 Min value : 5
-------------
Max Id : 35 Max value : 95
Min Id : 14 Min value : 3
-------------
Max Id : 5 Max value : 90
Min Id : 40 Min value : 1
-------------
Max Id : 4 Max value : 100
Min Id : 20 Min value : 3
-------------
Max Id : 9 Max value : 99
Min Id : 18 Min value : 4
-------------
Max Id : 5 Max value : 100
Min Id : 26 Min value : 2
-------------
Max Id : 26 Max value : 97
Min Id : 36 Min value : 3
-------------
Max Id : 2 Max value : 99
Min Id : 36 Min value : 1
-------------
Max Id : 33 Max value : 98
Min Id : 28 Min value : 7
-------------
Max Id : 3 Max value : 100
Min Id : 28 Min value : 1
-------------
Max Id : 5 Max value : 97
Min Id : 39 Min value : 1
-------------
Max Id : 4 Max value : 99
Min Id : 3 Min value : 4
-------------
```